# Is there a Grouped Product listing type in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I have a Magento site I would really like to migrate to Drupal Commerce.  The one must-have feature is Grouped Product.  A grouped product will have a base product from which the product listing will use the photos, description, etc.  The related products will provide their titles, prices, etc. to the product listing.  See the photo for an example.

Can this be done with Drupal Commerce?

Thanks for your time and help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal Commerce does differentiate between products and product variations same as other systems, but the feature you're looking for hasn't been ported to Drupal 8 yet. It's easy enough to create a table with individual Add to Cart buttons for the variations in Drupal 8, but to have a single Add to Cart button for all variations on a product page, you'd need this module upgraded for Drupal 8:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like from the question, and looks like from the photo example that you would like to sell multiple products as a "Set" (see photo) with one sku (see photo). If that's not the case, maybe add more detail regarding your use case.

> The "best" option out of the box:

There is not currently a **stable** bundle module for Drupal Commerce 2. [Commerce_product_bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle) for Drupal 8 accomplishes the function you want, but the module is not stable, nor under active development or maintenance. I would only install it for testing on a sandbox site, and would be hesitant using it in production in it's current state. [commerce_product_set](https://github.com/agoradesign/commerce_product_set) on github was developed because commerce_product_bundles was not production ready/ maintained.

So unfortunately, nothing is ready for this out of the box, so whatever choice you make will likely require some development.

[Commerce_bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bundle) for Drupal 7 is actually very dependable as a **dev** module, but I'm guessing you don't want to start with Drupal 7 at this point.

> Another suggestion:

There is also [product add on](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado) (pado) module for Drupal 8, but the use case is a little different than your example.

Sorry there is not better news.

Comment: This isn't really a product bundle scenario. This is more a question of a bulk add to cart for individual products.

Comment: From what was provided in the question and in the photo, I thought he wanted to sell what he called "groups" of products as a "Set" with a single SKU (see picture on both). Commerce product bundles (Though not stable) can of course handle the use case of adding multiple products at different quantities as a "Set" sold under one new sku "group". Not sure where the downvote came from :) The closest thing Drupal 8 has to offer on this out for the box that I am aware of is CPB.

Comment: You're right, it's a little ambiguous from just the information that was provided, since it doesn't show any behavior of the products in the cart itself.